# How to create a Timeline Progressbar Within Swiper slider : Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create a timeline slider something like facebook stories. For the slider I am using ngx-useful-swiper. I am trying to add a progress bar based on number of slides and the progress bar will increase based on the autoplay time.

Right now for the progress bar I am using this reference. https://codepen.io/mkwtzt/pen/QzKqym
But I cant not make it look like facebook stories slider. I want the progress bar look like this image [Slider Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNckS.jpg). Also there will are two buttons to pause and play the slider. How can i make autoplay stop and start by clicking on this two buttons?

**Html**

```
<div class="timeline-slider">
  <div id="progress"></div>
  <div class="swiper-action">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="play()">Play</a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="pause()">Pause</a>
  </div>
  <swiper [config]="config">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    </div>
  </swiper>
</div>
```

**Ts**

```
config: SwiperOptions = {
    autoplay: {
      delay: 5000,
      stopOnLastSlide : true,
      disableOnInteraction: false
    },
    spaceBetween: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    simulateTouch: false,
    effect: 'fade',
    on: {
      progress: () => {
        this.move();
      }
    } 
  }


  move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("progress"); 
    var width = 1;
    var autoplayTime = 5000 / 100;
    var id = setInterval(frame, autoplayTime);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
        }
    }
  }


 play(){
   console.log('play')
 }


 pause(){
   console.log('pause')
 }
```